# Disable Internet Explorer 11 Reading View for a web page

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way I can disable Internet Explorer 11's Reading View mode for a web page?

I.e. are there any meta tags or similar that I can include to discourage IE11 from displaying the "Reading View" button?

The reason I would like to do this is that the website in question is an application that has very little text (it is a calculator). As such, when someone clicks the "Reading View" button in the Internet Explorer 11 Modern App, it looks quite terrible - it displays a heading, a paragraph (help text for a question), and the footer copyright message.

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official documentation at IE Test Drive](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/browser/readingview) (click on "**</> Code**" and scroll to the bottom):

> For page owners who feel their content is not a good fit for Reading View, we offer a tag to opt out of Reading View. Once implemented, the Reading View icon will not appear in the address bar
>
> ```
> <meta name="IE_RM_OFF" content="true">
> ```